# WP and bootstrap: the_post_thumbnail() image breakes out the column

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I got a couple of col-sm-6 divs for a page. I use `the_post_thumbnail()` to get the page featured image and put it in the first col-sm-6 column but the image breaks out the column.

I could use "medium" as a parameter but I would like the image to fit that column width automatically.

How can I get it?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 page-frame">
    <h1 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
<div class="col-sm-6 page-frame">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are on the right track, in your css you would probably just do a `max-width: 100%;` or a `min-width: 100%;`

Comment: Thank you Ryan, it works but the image's been stretched: the width fits the div now but the height is the same of the original size.